# How to Sort records in SQL like in a parent child order

Tags: sql, sorting, columnsorting

I have a table with columns "ItemId" and "ParentItemId". I want the results to be sorted in Parent-Child Order. with this, there are other columns on which the data needs to be sorted.
I want the data to be sorted based on the "itemType" First.

For Eg.

```
 AutoId | itemId | parentItemId | itemType
   1        1       0               3
   2        2       null            4
   3        3       0               6
   4        4       null            5
   5        5        1              9
   6        6        2              9
   7        7        3              9
   8        8        4              9
   9        9        0              2
   10       10       0              1
```

Now I want the results to be drawn like in the below format

```
 AutoId | itemId | parentItemId | itemType
   10       10        0              1
   9        9         0              2
   1        1         0              3
   5        5         1              9
   2        2        null            4
   6        6         2              9
   4        4        null            5
   8        8         4              9
   3        3         0              6 
   7        7         3              9
```

Is there a way i can sort the records like this?

Any Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
select *
from table1
order by coalesce(parentitemid,itemid), itemid
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32e58e/2

Comment: This assumes that the parent's `itemid` will always be less than a child's `itemid`, but that seems like a reasonable assumption here.

Answer (score 1):

For MySql use ifnull for parentItemId field
Like

```
select *
from table
order by IFNULL(parentItemId, itemId), itemId
```

for oracle

```
select *
from table
order by NVL(parentItemId, itemId), itemId
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from @hkutluay answer for SQL Server:

`select * from table1 order by ISNULL(parentItemID, ItemID), ItemID`